# Unusual android logic operator not working comparing two strings

Tags: android, string, compare, logic, operator-keyword

I'm trying a simple check. If a string name locale has "es" as value.

```
public String locale = 
    Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().toLowerCase().toString();

// ...

Log.v(tag, "Idioma del sistema: «" + locale +"»");
if (locale != "es") {
    showDialog(R.string.warningTitleDialog, 
        "We are sorry that this tool is only available in Spanish " +
        "language. See Author menu item for more information. [" + 
        locale + "]");
    locale = "en";
}
```

`adb logcat` shows "es" as content of string "locale" but code inside the condition is being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seem that problem is not of android or of logic this is in JAVA.
Try this and tell us what is happening

```
if(!locale.equals("en"))
{
   //Your Code
}
```

Comment: == and != operator compares the addresses

Comment: Yes and that's why he always get false.

Answer (score 2):

Never use != or == in association with strings. Try the method equals like this:

```
if(locale.equals("es"))
```

This will return true if the strings locale and "es" contain the same character
sequence. Because the equals( ) method compares the characters inside a String object. The == operator compares two object references to see whether they refer to the same instance.

See [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) for more information.